# Why does my MacBook's screen continually dim and brighten without my input?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My MacBook Pro screen constantly dims and brightens.  The automatic box is unchecked.  The brightness adjustment button is constantly moving back and forth.

Comment: That sounds like a software issue. I would take it to an Apple Store if there is one close to you. If not, you may need to do a re-install.

Answer (score 11):

Go your System Preferences, select "Displays", and uncheck Auto-adjust Brightness.

Comment: Isn't this the same as the OP saying they unchecked the automatic box?

Answer (score 7):

Might be an issue with the power supply when “Slightly dim the display when on battery power” is checked in Energy Saver prefs. This would dim the display when the power adapter is lost and become brighter again when not running on battery anymore.

Comment: It's insane that this setting causes this behavior when I'm plugged in - I'm getting dim-throttled once every 2-3 seconds when plugged in.  Unchecking the box fixes it for me.  Thx.

Answer (score 5):

The "Auto-adjust Brightness" didn't fix it for me, but disabling the option right under it, "True Tone", did.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a *keyboard issue*. If other things are going wrong with keys, such as the backspace or caps lock, the keyboard (top case) needs replacing.

You can get a temporary fix by using a keyboard remapper program and change the keys for brightness and turn off the usual F1 and F2 ones.

Comment: That would indeed make sense since the screen brightness UI shows up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to reset the **System Management Controller** (SMC).

Apple's [documentation on the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) states that this may resolve issues related to the power management. The document specifically mentions:

> The display backlight doesn't respond correctly to ambient light changes on Mac computers that have this feature.

As the guidelines on how to reset the SMC depend on your kind of Mac, I will not list them all here. Please follow the link and go to the section with the title **Resetting the System Management Controller (SMC)** for more information on how to apply the reset.

Should that not work, you're left with two other avenues to remedy this:

- software errors - you might need to troubleshoot or restore the OS
- hardware fault - the display and sensor might simply need repair

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Ken's suggestion above (about disabling the "True Tone"), my True Tone was disabled so I clicked and enabled it, and my display went back to a bright screen again. Seems there's something about "True Tone" that is making this happen.

Comment: I think you're risking some site reputation with this answer.  It doesn't answer the OP's question and is just a comment on a different answer.  See [answer] for good info on writing answers.

Comment: No, Joni is exactly on point and on topic. There are different features that are misbehaving and causing the screen to dim when not required to.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the ambient light sensor?

Comment: As the OP states, the sensor is turned off in the System Preferences.